# Github action windows runner: How to remove all sh.exe from PATH

Tags: powershell, github-actions

Inside a github windows runner, I need to **remove** all `sh.exe` find from PATH otherwise my Make 4.3 based build will fail to correctly parse our Makefiles...

I currently see 2 solutions to fix it:

1. Remove all `sh.exe` dirname path from `PATH` (i.e. updating the `GITHUB_PATH`).
2. An other way could be to directly remove any `sh.exe` found in the windows action runner.

What I have tested so far without success...

1. First try

```yaml
- name: Remove sh.exe from PATH
  run: set GITHUB_PATH -= "/c/Program Files/Git/bin"
```

error: `A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '/c/Program Files/Git/bin'.`

2. Tried to use bash instead

```yaml
- name: Remove sh.exe from PATH
  run: |
        echo "$PATH"
        set PATH=%PATH:C:\Program Files\Git\bin;=%
        set PATH=%PATH:C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;=%
        echo "$PATH" > $GITHUB_PATH
  shell: bash
```

error: `line 2: =%: command not found`

### Annexe

Github only provide example for adding path to PATH not removing one.
ref: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#adding-a-system-path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get rid of `sh.exe` (i.e. solution 2)
you should try to add the following cmd to your `.yml` file:

```yaml
    - name: Find sh.exe
      run: where sh
    - name: remove Git\usr\bin\sh.exe
      run: rm 'C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\sh.exe'
      shell: bash
    - name: remove Git\bin\sh.exe
      run: rm 'C:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe'
      shell: bash
```

or

```yaml
    - name: Clean sh.exe
      run: |
        where sh
        rm 'C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\sh.exe'
        rm 'C:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe'
      shell: bash
```